# Passing props - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a problem I've been stuck on for a few hours now.

I have a component that when fired, it changes a const from "true" to "false". Using this information, I want to display a "sent" or "not sent" text div in another component.

For the life of me, I can not pass this prop into the other component.

I can not get the component ReadOnlyRow to read the prop sentStatus.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const TextForm = ({ contact, messageSent, props }) => {
  
  const [sentStatus, setSentStatus] = useState(true)
  const [sendTextText, setSendTextText] = useState("N/A")

  function sendText () {

    let phoneNumber = 1 + contact.phoneNumber
    
    //pass text message GET variables via query string
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/send-text?recipient=${phoneNumber}&textmessage=Dear ${contact.fullName}, Your liscnese is set to expre on 9/21`)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    console.log(contact.fullName)
    console.log(messageSent)
    
    console.log(sentStatus)
    setSentStatus(!sentStatus)
    
    if (sentStatus === true){
      setSendTextText('good')
      console.log("true")
    } else {
      setSendTextText('bad')
      console.log("false")
    }
    }


  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={sendText}>Send</button>
    <h1>{contact.phoneNumber}</h1>
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default TextForm;
```

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, Component } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import "./App.css";
import data from "./mock-data.json";
import ReadOnlyRow from "./components/ReadOnlyRow";
import EditableRow from "./components/EditableRow";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import TextForm from "./TextForm";

function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data)
  const [messageSent, setMessageSent] = useState(12)
  
  const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: ""
  });
  

  // const [textItem, setSet] = useState({
  //   text: {
  //     recipient: 'gorge',
  //     textmessage: 'gorgeous'
  //   }
  // })

  

  const [editFormData, setEditFormData] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const [editContactId, setEditContactId] = useState(null);

  const handleAddFormChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute("name");
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    const newFormData = { ...addFormData };
    newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;

    setAddFormData(newFormData);
  };
  

  const handleEditFormChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    

    const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute("name");
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    const newFormData = { ...editFormData };
    newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;

    setEditFormData(newFormData);

    
  };

  const handleAddFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newContact = {
      id: nanoid(),
      fullName: addFormData.fullName,
      address: addFormData.address,
      phoneNumber: addFormData.phoneNumber,
      email: addFormData.email,
    };

    const newContacts = [...contacts, newContact];
    setContacts(newContacts);
  };

  const handleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const editedContact = {
      id: editContactId,
      fullName: editFormData.fullName,
      address: editFormData.address,
      phoneNumber: editFormData.phoneNumber,
      email: editFormData.email,
    };

    const newContacts = [...contacts];

    const index = contacts.findIndex((contact) => contact.id === editContactId);

    newContacts[index] = editedContact;

    setContacts(newContacts);
    setEditContactId(null);
  };

  const handleEditClick = (event, contact) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEditContactId(contact.id);

    const formValues = {
      fullName: contact.fullName,
      address: contact.address,
      phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber,
      email: contact.email,
    };

    setEditFormData(formValues);
  };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    setEditContactId(null);
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (contactId) => {
    const newContacts = [...contacts];

    const index = contacts.findIndex((contact) => contact.id === contactId);

    newContacts.splice(index, 2);

    setContacts(newContacts);
  };
  
  function status ({sentStatus}) {
    console.log(sentStatus)
  }

  
    return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Header />
      <form onSubmit={handleEditFormSubmit}>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Guard #</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
              <th>Employee ID</th>
              <th>Expiration Date</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
              <th>Was the text sent out?</th>
              <th>Was an SMS sent?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {contacts.map((contacto) => (
              <Fragment>
                {editContactId === contacto.id ? (
                  <EditableRow
                    editFormData={editFormData}
                    handleEditFormChange={handleEditFormChange}
                    handleCancelClick={handleCancelClick}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <ReadOnlyRow
                    contact={contacto}
                    handleEditClick={handleEditClick}
                    handleDeleteClick={handleDeleteClick}
                    messageSent={messageSent}
                  />
                )}
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

      <h2>Add a Contact</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fullName"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a name..."
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter an addres..."
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="phoneNumber"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a phone number..."
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        />
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter an email..."
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextForm from "../TextForm";
import WasMessageSent from "./WasMessageSent";
import TextStatus from "./TextStatus";
import App from "../App";

const ReadOnlyRow = ({ contact, handleEditClick, handleDeleteClick, sentStatus, messageSent, sendo}, props) => {
  
  const [text, setText] = useState("yes")


  function status (){
    const gord = {sentStatus}
    console.log(gord)

  }

  

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{contact.fullName}</td>
      <td>{contact.address}</td>
      <td>{contact.phoneNumber}</td>
      <td>{contact.email}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={(event) => handleEditClick(event, contact)}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleDeleteClick(contact.id)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <TextForm 
        contact={contact}
        status={sentStatus}
        />
        <button>Send Email</button>
      </td>
      <td>Did they update it yet?</td>
      <td>{messageSent}</td>
      <td>{text}</td>
      <td><button onClick={status}>statuschecker</button></td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default ReadOnlyRow;
```

Comment: You are not using TextForm' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: TextForm is not inside of the Component folder. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I mean, TextForm is not used in App.js file

Comment: My issue is that I can't get it to read in ReadOnlyRow. I think the App.js is irrelevant in this example, I just included it for context.

Comment: what I mean is that you are not using TextForm anywhere you just created it but its not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple on how you can do it,

you create a state in the parent app, then you pass the state to the child component that needs it (ReadOnlyRow), and you pass the setState to the other child component (TextForm)

[image]

Here it is a simple demo, hopefully it will help you understand me better:

**The App Component**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import ReadOnlyRow from "./ReadOnlyRow";
import TextForm from "./TextForm";

function App() {
 
  const [sentStatus, setSentStatus] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
     <TextForm setSentStatus={setSentStatus} />
     <ReadOnlyRow sentStatus={sentStatus} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**The TextForm component**

```js
import React from "react";

const TextForm = ({ setSentStatus }) => {
  
  const sendText = () => {
    setSentStatus(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sendText}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextForm;
```

**The ReadOnlyRow component**

```js
import React from "react";

const ReadOnlyRow = ({ sentStatus }) => {

  return (
   <p>
      {sentStatus ? 'sent' : 'not sent'}
   </p>
  );
};

export default ReadOnlyRow;
```

Comment: Wow thank you for detailed answer! Was my problem thay I declared sentStatus not in the parent component (app.js)? My issue is I am trying to get sentText, which I declared in TextForm.js, to read in ReadOnlyRow.

Comment: For some reason, my set function is not reading in TextForm.js. I'm getting the folllowing:
```
TypeError: setMessageSent is not a function
sendText
src/components/TextForm.js:21
  18 | console.log(contact.fullName)
  19 | 
  20 | 
> 21 | setMessageSent(true)
     | ^  22 | 
  23 | }
  24 |
```

Comment: Actually realized my issue now, but stil not sure how I can solve. <TextForm/> is called in ReadOnlyRow, where as ReadOnlyRow, the attributes are givin in App.JS. I can't seem to pass setSent through ReadOnlyRow.js, only within App.js

Comment: @beniboy I am not sure if I understood you well (<TextForm/> is called in ReadOnlyRow) !! , but here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-hellman-0k34v, if you can make a codesandbox with your issue, I might be able understand you better